Python Script to scan a host cipher suites
I try to write a script like "sslscan" to scan and grab all cipher suites that a website is using.
This is my sample code. This code only grabs one cipher.
import ssl
import socket

def ssl_scan(hostname, port):
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
            cipher_suites = ssock.cipher()
            print(cipher_suites)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hostname = "host.co,"
    port = 443
    ssl_scan(hostname, port)

I want to print all cipher suites.

Indeed, it prints the one actually in use for the connection, not the ones offered when the connection was set up. You'll need to delve deeper into the connection setup code to see that.

In TLS, the client offers a list of cipher suites and the server picks one. I presume that programs like sslscan get around this by attempting to make a TLS connection with a single ciphersuite, recording whether it was sucessful, then closing the TLS connection and repeating the process with the next ciphersuite.

Try ssock.shared_ciphers() instead of ssock.cipher()
cipher() will only give you currently in use cipher.
